# Can someone explain the Navier Stokes equations?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

I am doing a research work on the Navier stokes equations but I don't really understand them, as I am a high school student. Could someone explain them to me in an easy way but kind of specific? Thank you

Comment: Duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/305877/

Comment: In short, they are the usual conservation laws (conservation of mass, of momentum, of energy...) per unit volume of fluid. They're stated either with differentials or integrals, so they're not suitable for high school students. Just think of "chicken entering in = chicken going out".

Comment: The Navier Stokes equation is a combination of two other equations.  The first is a Newton's 2nd law force balance equation (force = mass x acceleration) on each small parcel of the fluid, and includes gravitational forces and contact forces (exerted by adjacent fluid parcels) on the parcel under consideration.  The other equation is one which describes the viscous deformational behavior of the parcel of fluid in terms of the relationship between the forces acting on the parcel and its deformational response to these forces.

Comment: @FGSUZ - lol what a random statement: "chicken going = chicken going out", what about "chicken  production" and "chicken destruction" and "chicken rubbing too much together so they lose feathers and become less chicken"? How is this highschool student to understand your chicken metaphor for fluid flow?

Comment: spontaneous creation and destruction of chicken is meant to count in "entering" and "exiting" haha.